# how to replace datamaper in Mule CE

Tags: mule, esb

i need to send json to a web service and getting the response in json format.
so firstly i have a http connecter which receive data and then i need a datamaper to map the json that i get to the web service. in a second flow i put another http connecter which listen to the web service and get the response. actually what i need is an element who can replace the datamaper because i'm working with the community version. so if there is any example of code any tutorial, i would be grateful.

First flow:

```
<flow name="Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"
            contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" path="getDetails" />
        <json:json-to-object-transformer
            returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="tkn"
            value="#[message.payload.token]" doc:name="token" />
        <set-session-variable variableName="msg"
            value="#[message.payload.msg]" doc:name="message" />

        <logger message="#[sessionVars['tkn']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

    </flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do your own mapping in a custom component or use a framework like [Smooks](http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) to do the transformations. If you choose the latter you can check out this [blog post](http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-trials-of-smooks.html). HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Any example of the first solution please?!

Comment: Sorry I don't have one. All you need is to extract the values from the incoming message and build a request specific for your web service.

Answer (score 0):

Rajeun,

Refer the below link if that helps.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JSON+Module+Reference

Comment: thank you for your reply, I've seen the link but i think that i need how to build json. because firstly i get json then i transfom it with json to object after i get a new data from database (objects) and i have finaly to transfort all of this data to a json which will be sent to a web service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow following steps :-
1. Extract the data from your input Json request and store in variables.
2. Now, if your external service is a SOAP, then you can create a SOAP request using **XSLT** example :- http://bushorn.com/xml-to-xml-transformation-in-mule/
3. If your external web service is a REST, you can create the JSON request for that service using Mule **Expression transformer** example :- http://bushorn.com/json-to-json-transformation-in-mule/